# How to parsing LocalDateTime from RestController in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, datetime-format, spring-restcontroller

I'm trying to implement a controller for my application using kotlin. But there are an error when parsing the datetime format when I make a get request.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/records")
class RecordController(val recordService: RecordService) {

  @GetMapping("details")
  fun getRecordDetail(
    @RequestParam recordId: Int,
    @RequestParam(required = false) @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) dateTime: LocalDateTime): RecordDto {
    return recordService.getRecordDetails(recordId, dateTime)
  }
}
```

The error is

```
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDateTime'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: 
Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.time.LocalDateTime] for value '2017-08-21T00:00:000.00'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Parse attempt failed for value [2017-08-21T00:00:000.00]"
```

The rest api works fine without the dateTime parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you provide a value with a format not compatible with the defined `ISO`-date.

Here your value (maybe just a "typo" from your side) and a working value

```
2017-08-21T00:00:000.00   (yours)
2017-08-21T00:00:00.000   (working)
```

Ensure that you provide a valid second and millisecond value.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I have not checked correctly. Thanks so much